# Pandas - change the order of levels of factor-type object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` with column `school` as factor

```
Name    school
A       An
B       Bn
C       Bn
```

How can I change the levels of the `school` column from ('An', 'Bn') to ('Bn', 'An') in python?

R equivalent is

```
levels(df$school) = c('Bn','An')
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use [`reorder_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.reorder_categories.html) (you pass in the sorted factors):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
  Name school
0    A     An
1    B     Bn
2    C     Bn

In [12]: df['school'] = df['school'].astype('category')

In [13]: df['school']
Out[13]:
0    An
1    Bn
2    Bn
Name: school, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [An, Bn]

In [14]: df['school'].cat.reorder_categories(['Bn', 'An'])
Out[14]:
0    An
1    Bn
2    Bn
dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [Bn, An]
```

You can do this inplace:

```
In [21]: df['school'].cat.reorder_categories(['Bn', 'An'], inplace=True)

In [22]: df['school']
Out[22]:
0    An
1    Bn
2    Bn
Name: school, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [Bn, An]
```

[*See the reordering categories section of the docs*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#reordering).

Comment: My original answer used categoricals as well, but I am also not familiar enough with R to infer whether the OP is simply renaming values or else reordering categories.

Answer (score 6):

You can set `cat.categories`:

```
import pandas as pd

school = pd.Series(["An", "Bn", "Bn"])
school = school.astype("category")

school.cat.categories = ["Bn", "An"]
```

Comment: I guess that's not what the OP wants. `pandas.Series.cat.categories` replaces the values in the data set themselves using an input list (so level `"An"` would now be `"Bn"` and vice versa) whereas the question was to only change the order of levels.

Comment: I agreed with @JohannesWiesner, in this way, the levels are renamed.

Answer (score 1):

As a general solution, you can remap using a dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'school': ['An', 'Bn', 'Bn']})
d = {'An': 'Bn', 'Bn': 'An'}
df['school'] = df.school.map(d)
>>> df
  Name school
0    A     Bn
1    B     An
2    C     An
```

Comment: I don't know R well enough to say if this is correct, or my answer. Depends on OPs intention I guess!